# How to do top image transition to show the background image while scrolling

Tags: reactjs, css, sass

I'm doing SPA wherein I've sticky header and a half background image with 3 cards (having a title and image) on, the only thing I'm being stuck is when, I scroll down the top image must have transitioned. when the page is getting scrolled the background image should appear in that much of image transition. when I scroll back up the image must do transition expanding itself and hiding the background image.

`post.scss`:

```
@import '../scss/common.scss';

.container{
    background-image: url("../images/bg2.jpg") ;
    height:80%;
    //background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.header{
    // background-color: $primary-background;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    // color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 50px;
}

    .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .blank{
    height: 800px;
    }
```

`post.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import TitleContainer from '../container/titleContainer';
import './post.scss';
import Cards from '../container/cards';
import imgT from '../images/city1.jpg';
class Post extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={

        }
        this.header = React.createRef();
    }

    handscroll=(e)=>{
        const node = this.header.current;
        let sticky=node.offsetTop
        //console.log(node)
    // console.log(sticky)
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
            node.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            node.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
        // console.log(e)

    }  

    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handscroll)
    }
    render(){

        return(
            <div className="container" > 
                <div className="header" ref={this.header}>
                    <TitleContainer title="World Top Cities"/>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    <Cards title="t1" cntryImg={imgT} />
                    <Cards title="t2" cntryImg={imgT} />
                    <Cards title="t3" cntryImg={imgT} />
                    <div className="blank"></div>                                 
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Post;
```

`card.scss`:

```
%common-all{
    width: 100%;

}
//border:1px solid #80808040;
        //height:250px;
    // border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px ;

@mixin commonFn($border,$height,$borderRadius){
        border:$border;
        height:$height;
        border-radius: $borderRadius ;
}

.container3{
@extend %common-all;
// border-radius: 40px;
margin-top:3%;
    .title{
        @extend %common-all;
        @include commonFn(1px solid #80808040,50px,15px 15px 0 0);
        background-color: white;
    }
    .cntryImg{
        @extend %common-all;
        @include commonFn(0,250px,0 0 15px 15px)
    }

}
```

`cards.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../scss/cards.scss'

class Cards extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container3"> 
                <div className="title">
                    {this.props.title}
                </div>
                < div className="cntryImg1">
                <img src={this.props.cntryImg} alt="noImg" className="cntryImg"/>
                </div>

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Cards;
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong, I do have any much no idea how do I approach it. when the page is getting scrolled down the background image should appear in that much of image transition (here image transists). When I scroll back up the image must do transition expanding itself and hiding the background image. 
Please help I'm stuck past two days. Let me know if I'm not clear. Please help me on how doing it.

Updated

No, not height theirs half background image, out of 3 "containers3"(cards) 2 "containers3"(cards) covering the background image one is white background when I scroll down there should be transition effect the suppose 10px (just for ex) I scroll only that many pixels transition must happen for that particular card (not hidden at once transition effect way of hiding and showing background image when scroll up or down respectively) and background image for that particular 10px must be shown, position must not change. (here theirs transition way of hiding and showing background image)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong..You want to change background image height as you scroll.so that when scrolling down,height increases and vice versa.am I correct?

Comment: Instead of calculating with pageOffsets on every scroll you should take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API Intersection Observers, this should help you. (Even tough you have to rewrite your code for the API)

Comment: @cloned can you please share any demo online with snippet or some working link